# RBAC for basic yii2 template

Tags: php, yii2, rbac

i want to create an application where only admin can perform all the crud operations but other users can only create and update posts.  I did find tutorials based on rbac but only for advanced template but i am using the basic template. I also followed the yii2 guide but i did not understood it very well like executing ./yii rbac/init console command. How do i do it?

Comment: Hi @Raj. Same Problem is with me too. Where i've to declare DB with role = 100 ? In config/db.php ?

Comment: @NanaPartykar sorry, I no longer code in yii2.

Comment: Ok @Raj. NP. Thanku.

Comment: http://www.freetuts.org/tutorial/view?id=6 This link will surely help you to learn in detail and implement RBAC in Yii2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all create a Helper Class called PermissionHelpers in your model folder:

```
namespace app\models;
use Yii;

class PermissionHelpers {

    public static function requireAdmin() {

        if(Yii::$app->user->identity->role == 100)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
}
```

Then update your controller with:

```
// at top with your other use
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use app\models\PermissionHelpers;


// first function inside the class
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'only' => ['privateaction1', 'privateaction2'],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['privateaction1', 'privateaction2'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                    'matchCallback' => function($rule, $action) {
                            return PermissionHelpers::requireAdmin();
                        }
                ],
            ],
        ],
}
```

And now you need to update yourself in the DB with role = 100, and you're set.

I'm using Advanced template myself, so there might be small changes to the namespaces and such. But it should be fairly easy to figure out. Good luck!

Comment: Hi @Jorgen. Then We can use RBAC in yii2-basic version. Is it ? Because, while reading yii2-rbac tutorial, i found that RBAC is for yii2-advanced version.