# Add custom RBAC rule to PhpManager in Yii 2.0

Tags: php, yii, yii2, rbac

I want to add a custom rule to PhpManager RBAC in Yii 2.0.

Here is the custom rule (@app/rbac/OwnerRule.php):

```
<?php

namespace app\rbac;

use yii\rbac\Rule;

/**
 * Checks if userID matches user passed via params
 */
class OwnerRule extends Rule
{
    public $name = 'isOwner';

    public function execute($user, $item, $params)
    {
        $access = false;
        if(isset($params['id'])){ 
            // My custom logic used to set $access
        }

        return $access;
    }
}
```

Here is the RBAC hierarchy file (@app/data/rbac.php)

```
<?php
use yii\rbac\Item;

return [
    'manageThing0' => ['type' => Item::TYPE_OPERATION, 'description' => '...', 'bizRule' => NULL, 'data' => NULL],
    'manageThing1' => ['type' => Item::TYPE_OPERATION, 'description' => '...', 'bizRule' => NULL, 'data' => NULL],
    'manageThing2' => ['type' => Item::TYPE_OPERATION, 'description' => '...', 'bizRule' => NULL, 'data' => NULL],

    // AND THE ROLES
    'guest' => [
        'type' => Item::TYPE_ROLE,
        'description' => 'Guest',
        'bizRule' => NULL,
        'data' => NULL
    ],

    'user' => [
        'type' => Item::TYPE_ROLE,
        'description' => 'User',
        'children' => [
            'guest',
            'manageThing0', // User can edit thing0
        ],
        'bizRule' => 'return !Yii::$app->user->isGuest;',
        'data' => NULL
    ],

    'moderator' => [
        'type' => Item::TYPE_ROLE,
        'description' => 'Moderator',
        'children' => [
            'user',         // Can manage all that user can
            'manageThing1', // and also thing1
        ],
        'bizRule' => NULL,
        'data' => NULL
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'type' => Item::TYPE_ROLE,
        'description' => 'Admin',
        'children' => [
            'moderator',    // can do all the stuff that moderator can
            'manageThing2', // and also manage thing2
        ],
        'bizRule' => NULL,
        'data' => NULL
    ],

];
```

How do I use my custom rule in the hierarchy file?

Answer (score 0):

See these links hope you will find what you are looking for,

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html

http://yii2-user.dmeroff.ru/docs/custom-access-control

[RBAC for basic yii2 template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27542907/rbac-for-basic-yii2-template?rq=1)

Comment: It's good information.  I am not marking the question answered though because the links don't directly answer the question.